# Bug in R's grepl?

Tags: regex, r, grepl

Here's my script:

```
a<-list("abcd")
b<-list("abcd_efgh")
c<-"abcd"
d<-"abcd_efgh"

if(grepl(a,b,fixed=TRUE))
{
    print("bug?")
}

if(grepl(c,d,fixed=TRUE))
{
    print("bug?")
}
```

And my output:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
[1] "bug?"
[1] "bug?"
```

Since I've provided 'fixed=TRUE', I'm confused what I'm missing.
Is this a bug in grepl folks?

Comment: Why do you think it  a bug? It is an expected behavior.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the expected behavior.  in your first comparison, you're looking for `"abcd"` in `"abcd_efgh"`.  Were you thinking you were performing `grepl(b, a, fixed=TRUE)`?

Comment: This is the normal behavior. Look at `?grepl`.

Comment: Downvoted, it's unclear what you're asking about, at least write what you expected before asking for a bug...

Comment: @VenkatRamakrishnan: Please update the question to let us know what you thought and tried to achieve. Or let me know if you want to remove the question, I will remove my answer.

Comment: Obviously ping me with @Tensibai once edited if you do so, I'll review my vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, see [`grepl` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

> **`grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,`
>
>         `fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)`**
>
> `pattern` 
>   character string containing a regular expression (***or character string for `fixed = TRUE`***) to be matched in the given character vector. Coerced by `as.character` to a character string if possible. If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning. Missing values are allowed except for `regexpr` and `gregexpr`.
>
> **`fixed`**
>   logical. **If `TRUE`, pattern is a string to be matched as is**. Overrides all conflicting arguments.

So, you are searching for `abcd` in `abcd_efgh`, which is `true`. You are not requiring a *full string match* when setting `fixed=TRUE`, just all the characters used in the pattern cannot be regex metacharacters.

Comment: I upvoted as the explanation is clear, but I still doubt this kind of question badly stated should be answered. Just my opinion.

Comment: It does not look that bad to me. I have seen much poorer questions this year. It is clear to me OP wanted to ensure a full string match (as with Java's `String#matches`).

Comment: In my opinion, a question asking if something is a bug when not stating what was expected is poorly written. As said above (by upvoting), your answer sounds nice to me by explaining the doc, but you had to guess what the OP expected (and maybe it's wrong and it's not what the OP is asking about)